# How to logout from this forum?

Tags: discussion

I'm new here and can see in the right top corner my login-icon.

But I do not manage to find out how to logout.

What do I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Stack button:

[image]

And use the log out link:

[image]